# Is there a page formatting change at 2000 reputation?

Tags: support, design

I have just reached 2000 reputation, and since I have used this website for a while, I noticed that my homepage had changed format. I don't know how this happened. Is this a specific system feature or something else?

[image]

Comment: The Meta homepage has not changed, for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you've accidentally tripped the [mobile version of the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mobile-web/info). That setting is stored per-site in a cookie, so that's why you still see the full version of the Meta site.

To go back to the full version, scroll down to the bottom and click the 'Full site' link:

[image]

Comment: oops. And I gave away 50 of my rep just to 'get back to the original site'.